# iOS: Crashlytics Crashing on Init

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics

In my AppDelegate, I call

```
[Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
```

and everything works fine. Now I pulled my code onto another machine, and the same line gives me the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'FabricException', reason: '[Fabric] Value of Info.plist key "Fabric" must be a NSDictionary.'
```

I'm not aware of any additions in my project's plist. Any ideas what this error may be referring to and how to fix it?

Comment: did you try to reinstall fabric?

Comment: An update was needed. Just for that target, apparently. We have 3 other targets that had the latest version while the broken one had an older version. Once we updated that target's Crashlytics through Fabric, everything worked fine.

Comment: @Maxwell post your own answer and mark it as accepted please.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Fabric automatically inserts of hunk of text into your application's plist when you install it. These are essential and Fabric throws an exception on initialisation if they're not present.

Unfortunately it doesn't actually tell you it does this, so we ran into this crash on a project where the plist was automatically generated by a tool - which overwrote what Fabric had added.

For reference, this is what the Fabric part of the plist looks like in the current version (not sure where the version number is, but the latest version as of 15th June 2015).

```
<key>Fabric</key>
<dict>
        <key>APIKey</key>
        <string>your-api-key</string>
        <key>Kits</key>
        <array>
                <dict>
                        <key>KitInfo</key>
                        <dict/>
                        <key>KitName</key>
                        <string>Crashlytics</string>
                </dict>
        </array>
</dict>
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me too. I'd started using cocoapods to require Crashlytics and this was giving me the same error until I added to the plist

Answer (score 5):

One more way to solve this Using Fabric App.

1. Launch Fabric app and log in with your user ID.
2. Click on Add New App
3. Select your .xcodeproj file and follow on screen instruction

Do not manually add Fabric key in your .info plist file

Answer (score 2):

The solution required us to update Crashlytics. The other targets that we had set up had the latest version and those were working fine, but the latest update (3.0.9 at the time of this post) seems to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2):

It just happened to me and this is how I solved it (thanks for the leads to everyone.)

**Context**: When you have more than one different target in your Xcode project, by creating a New App in the Mac Fabric app is, apparently, not enough.

**Solution**: If you select the same project (to make it for your Pro version for instance) Fabric app does not touch the Pro´s .plist properly.
So just copy the Fabric dictionary entry of your non-pro version of .plist and paste it into your Pro´s version.
API key goes on Organisation level, so this is the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

just change the Fabric key type from String to Dictionary. go to your-project-info.plist>Fabric>kits>item0>KitName and change type to Dictionary. problem resolved for me

Answer (score 0):

May be this will look weird but the same problem happened to me and this is how i solved the problem. I have a project with multiple target and schemes, i have also two additional targets for unit tests and UI Tests. The solution was to uncheck these tests targets from "Analyse", "Run", "Profile" and "Archive" tabs under Manage Schemes > Edit > Build. See the image Below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For me the reason was:

While you are creating a new target - a new Info.plist files is created automatically. 
Thus you need to put the Fabric property to all Info.plist files.

```
<key>Fabric</key>
<dict>
    <key>APIKey</key>
    <string>43336ce109856f4452829a8e6b6783886fefb</string>
    <key>Kits</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>KitInfo</key>
            <dict/>
            <key>KitName</key>
            <string>Crashlytics</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
```

At first I've missed that, and put this code only to the first one - initial Info.plist file.

Comment: Of course, this was a long time ago, but you probably don't want your Fabric APIKey published.  Maybe want to edit it out of your post.

Answer (score 0):

my two cents:
in my all I add for mistake to plist of "myAppTests" and not to "myApp" plist.
So as also Eugene noted, be careful to add in EVERY .plist.